PydanticOutputParser.parse() giving the error: Model expected dict not list (type=type_error)
I am working with data generation and using Pydantic classes to do so. The data will be used for calling REST APIs, so the model looks like this along with parsing code:
class NEFDataModel(BaseModel):
    request: str = Field(description="A question about utilizing the NEF API to perform a specific action.")
    api_call: str = Field(description="The full URL (taken from the 'path' field) of the API endpoint being invoked.")
    description: str = Field(description="A brief summary of the purpose of the API endpoint.")
    method: str = Field(description="The HTTP method used to call the API endpoint.")
    operation: str = Field(description="The operationId of the API endpoint.")
    parameters: dict = Field(description="Any parameters required by the API endpoint, a comma separated dict of key-value pairs.")

nef_output_parser = PydanticOutputParser(pydantic_object=NEFDataModel)

....

output_dict = nef_output_parser.parse(response.content)

However, I am getting the following error on calling nef_output_parser.parse(response.content):
  NEFDataModel expected dict not list (type=type_error)
If I print the response.contentfrom the invoked chain (without calling parser on it), it looks like this:
[
  {
    "request": "How can I obtain an access token for future requests?",
    "api_call": "/api/v1/login/access-token",
    "description": "OAuth2 compatible token login, get an access token for future requests",
    "method": "post",
    "operation": "login_access_token_api_v1_login_access_token_post",
    "parameters": {
      "grant_type": "password",
      "username": "your_username",
      "password": "your_password",
      "scope": "",
      "client_id": "your_client_id",
      "client_secret": "your_client_secret"
    }
  },
...
]

I have tried playing with data types but no use. And according to my analysis so far, the parameters field is causing the issue.

The issue is resolved now. Yes I needed to use RootModel. It somehow looks like this now:
class NEFDataModel(BaseModel):
request: str = Field(description="A question about utilizing the NEF API to perform a specific action.")
api_call: str = Field(description="The full URL (taken from the 'path' field) of the API endpoint being invoked.")
description: str = Field(description="A brief summary of the purpose of the API endpoint.")
method: str = Field(description="The HTTP method used to call the API endpoint.")
operation: str = Field(description="The operationId of the API endpoint.")
parameters: object = Field(description="Any parameters required by the API endpoint, a comma separated dict of key-value pairs.")

from pydantic import RootModel

class NEFDataModels(RootModel):
root: list[NEFDataModel]


nef_instruction_parser = PydanticOutputParser(pydantic_object=NEFDataModel)
nef_output_parser = PydanticOutputParser(pydantic_object=NEFDataModels)


If you have several NEFDataModel in response.content, you need a RootModel to parse them into a list.
from pydantic import RootModel

class NEFDataModels(RootModel):
    root: list[NEFDataModel]

nef_output_parser = PydanticOutputParser(pydantic_object=NEFDataModels)



I tried what you suggested and this line format_instructions = nef_output_parser.get_format_instructions() threw following error:
pydantic.errors.PydanticInvalidForJsonSchema: Cannot generate a JsonSchema for core_schema.PlainValidatorFunctionSchema ({'type': 'with-info', 'function': <bound method BaseModel.validate of <class '__main__.NEFDataModel'>>})

For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.6/u/invalid-for-json-schema

